# Can't update the item on change - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a Post component imported as a module and a flatlist on my Home screen. When I click on the button on Post component, I want the flatlist on homepage to get the change and update the selected index. But I guess something is missing.

Post.js //

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps.data.is_bookmarked != this.state.data.is_bookmarked) {
       this.setState({data: nextProps.data})
       return true
    }
    else {
        return false
    }
}
```

...

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
     if(this.props.onConfirmed != undefined) {
     this.props.onConfirmed(!this.state.data.is_bookmarked);
     }
}}>
```

Home Page //

```
renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
        <Post

        onConfirmed={(index) => {

            this.setState((prevstate) => {
            prevstate.is_bookmarked = !item.is_bookmarked
            return prevstate

        })

        }}

        key = {item.id + '-' + item.is_bookmarked}

        data={item}

        ></Post>
    );
}
```

...

```
<FlatList
        data={this.state.data}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
/>
```

Comment: what is the structure of the data array and how do you want the change to happen?

Comment: Add `extraData={this.state.data}` to your flatlist.

Comment: data: require('../../modules/post_data.json')

Comment: Can you copy a part of the file post_data.json and update your post with it?

Comment: If your post component is an independent React.Component then this is behaving as expected. Calling setState inside a component only triggers a re-render for that component(and its children) without notifying its parent. One way would be to pass a function as a prop that updates the state on your Home Page